# Pronunciation of anonymize

Tags: pronunciation

I [“googled” the word anonymize](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+anonymize) to verify its spelling because it is not in the Chrome’s dictionary. Before I closed the tab, on a whim, I clicked the little speaker icon to hear Google’s pronunciation of the word and was taken aback. Google seems to think that the word is pronounced `/əˈnänəˌmīz/`.

That seemed wrong because while I don’t recall hearing anyone say the word *anonymize*, I certainly never said it like that. More over, nobody pronounces *anonymous* in that manner, so I can’t imagine why the variant should be any different.

From what I can tell, it looks like [everybody else agrees with me](https://www.google.com/search?q=anonymize%20pronunciation) on the pronunciation, which leaves me wondering where/how the heck Google got that awkward pronunciation. The obvious guess was that, as usual, it scraped it from Wiktionary or Wikipedia, but I did not see any such indication there.

The dictionary section does not give any indications of where they draw their references, so I am left wondering if that really is an actual pronunciation of the word or if Google just messed up.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, it was the second result in my second link and it agrees with my pronunciation and disagrees with Google’s.

Comment: (Hmm, doing a text-search for the IPA shown in the definition section gives no hits in the search results, but if you google just `anonymize` and search for just `nə`, then it finds Merriam Webster as the 4th result which seems to give that pronunciation. I couldn’t check the MW page itself because it requires a subscription, which begs the question does Google have a subscription to MW which they use for their definitions? ಠ_ఠ)

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anonymous): **anonymous:** /ə-ˈnä-nə-məs/. But Merriam-Webster believes all unstressed syllables should be pronounced with /ə/. That is, they have the [weak merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Weak-vowel_merger).

Comment: What's the umlaut on /nä/ for? That's no English phoneme. That means they're using their own house style, like Merriam-Webster. and that means that what they call  /i/ could be a "long I" and therefore "miz" could mean /mayz/. The causative suffix is always pronounced /-ayz/, afaik.

Comment: `> The audio clip on oxforddictionaries (second link on OP's search) sounds perfectly ordinary to me. What's supposed to be wrong with it` @FumbleFingers, nothing. But what does that have to do with anything? I’m asking about Google’s pronunciation.

Comment: @JohnLawler, it looks like that might be the case. [One person got no answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/ecssPhOiBZA) as to Google’s source, while [another page indicates](http://lifehacker.com/5418921/google-does-its-own-dictionary-definitions) that they make/made up their own.

Comment: @PeterShor, thanks for the information, I actually read up on that a few weeks ago. However, the problem is with the second syllable. Like with the word `anonymous`, it should be pronounced `non`, not `nen` like Google does.

Comment: If the Google pronunciation symbols are from Merriam-Webster (and I'm pretty sure they get their phonetic transcription from M-W), it actually says to pronounce it *non* and not *nen* (or at least, the way Americans pronounce *non*). That's ***not*** a German a-umlaut. I don't know where Google gets their audio clips from.

Comment: Executive Summary: Do not trust transcriptions on Google. For pronunciations, find a native speaker.

Comment: @John: the transcription is perfectly fine (assuming you understand Merriam-Webster's notation). The pronunciation is atrocious—/ˈænoʊnɪˌmaɪz/, I think—and disagrees with the transcription. But I suspect it's a native speaker who just doesn't know how to pronounce the word.

Comment: Basically, he's pronouncing it like *anonymity* rather than *anonymous*.

Comment: Why would anyone understand M-W's flavor of phonetics? Generations of schoolchildren have stared at the pronunciation guide, with its italics and macrons and semimacrons, its diareses and breves and whatnots, and had their eyes glazed over. And no help from their teachers, who'd glazed completely long ago. It wasn't until I studied phonetics (which I should have done in grade school) that I got any stable representation of speech. And then I found that M-W publishes Kenyon and Knott but won't use it in their dictionaries. Hopeless.

Comment: @John: if you actually have M-W in hard copy or online, you can find their key for phonetic symbols.  So it's possible to decode. (And generations of Americans, like me, grew up using them, which is probably why they don't change.) But if you just see Google using their transcription, I don't know how on earth you'd figure out what all those funny marks mean. So maybe M-W has an excuse for using them, but Google has absolutely none.

Comment: Exactly. I used to be a whiz at M-W in grade school, but I always thought it was a poor way to do it, mixing up spelling and pronunciation as it does. But every other dictionary used **their** own proprietary brands, and later editions changed it, so I gave up in disgust. Nobody else I knew ever got any good at it, and I never knew anybody to look up and use a pronunciation in an M-W dictionary. Except -- ironically -- [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse?ui=embed#page/n5/mode/2up), which is published but not used by M-W.

Comment: @JohnLawler M-W is the best-selling dictionary of English. http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Books-Dictionaries-Thesauruses/zgbs/books/11475 The average speaker of American English is more likely to have a copy of that dictionary than any other, so their system for pronunciations is probably the best-known in the United States. In any case, their very well-written explanation of their system includes IPA meanings for each symbol http://www.merriam-webster.com/help/MWOL%20Pronunciation%20Guide.pdf including all the variations used in common IPA systems for English (which are not standard).

Answer (score 1):

According to Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary by Daniel Jones, the only viable pronunciation for ***anonymize/anonymise*** is:

> [əˈnɒnɪmɑɪz] OR [əˈnɒnəmɑɪz] (for the Brits); [əˈnɑːnəmɑɪz] (AmE)

This is the "WORLD'S MOST TRUSTED pronouncing dictionary"; the cover of the 18th edition says it, I don't.

According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anonymize?s=t), it's /əˈnɒnɪˌmaɪz/, which is the same.

Accordin to [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/ru/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/anonymize), it's /əˈnɒnɪmʌɪz/, which is the same.

According to [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anonymize), it's \ə-ˈnä-nə-ˌmīz\, which is the same.

If Google's transcription of the word is /əˈnänəˌmīz/, Meriam-Webster (has the same thing) pronounces it just fine.

Trust but verify. If you're 100% sure they stress the first syllable in anonymize, they messed it up.

Comment: Oxford, which is the only one of your citations to provide audio, stresses the second syllable not (as Google) the first, which makes it appear that the problem is different transcriptions. Perhaps you could save your scorn till you are sure what is being asked?

Comment: ok,  i think he said "Google seems to think that the word is pronounced /əˈnänəˌmīz/", which seems perfectly fine and he asked "I am left wondering if that really is an actual pronunciation of the word" are you ok with that?

Comment: @TimLymington - The Merriam-Webster citation provides audio.  (And it pronounces it "correctly".)